# Can I use an Access 2010 Database with SharePoint 2013

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010, database-connection, sharepoint-2013

Couldn't find any research on it online. Would love some insight before I download.

I did find one link, but not sure if what's listed is something extra I need to purchase or something I already have.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748653.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you most certainly can use Access 2010 with SharePoint 2013.

In fact the real issue is if your instance of SharePoint is running Access web services. This is a requirement to use Access web publishing. The basic version of SharePoint does not include Access Web services (and thus no web publishing).

However all the basic SharePoint versions allow you to migrate tables from Access to SharePoint. So you can migrate your tables to SharePoint, and Access as a front end can use the linked table on SharePoint. And thus Access 2010 will work with SP 2013 in this regards,

However, if your 2013 SharePoint does not have Access web services, you cannot use the Access web publishing feature.

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful! Fortunately I did have Access Web Services.